# is it possible to change the OpenMP scheduler for tasks?

Tags: gcc, scheduling, openmp, libgomp

Can I provide an implementation specific scheduler? If so, is there some documentation about how to do it?

Comment: No, you can't. The task scheduler is part of the OpenMP run-time `libgomp`. You can, of course, provide your own implementation of the [libgomp ABI](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libgomp/The-libgomp-ABI.html#The-libgomp-ABI) which can be preloaded or linked to instead, pretty much as the [ForestGOMP](http://runtime.bordeaux.inria.fr/forestgomp/) run-time does.

Comment: alternatively you could use Intel TBB as they provide a lot more setting possibilities - please see https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/ (warning: something is wrong with ssl certificate)